# Chrome extension not syncing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I wrote a google chrome extension which should sync data to my chrome profile to all of my computers.
Therefore i'm using the chrome storage api: [Google Chrome Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#overview)

I'm able to store and read the data on my primary pc. But on my other computer the data is not accessible.

I'm using the same profile on both computers. And i'm using the `chrome.storeage.sync` methods.
Because i don't want to publish the extension now i installed the extension with the developer mode activated and not over the chrome store.
Is this the reason why the data is not syncing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i now published my app to the chrome store and now it's syncing.
So syncing is not working while your extension is under development.